# Prove that operator L on $M_n(\mathbb F)$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to slove the following problem:

"Let $M_n(\mathbb F)$ be the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices over a filed $\mathbb{F}$ and let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ be an invertible matrix and diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}$. Consider the linear operator $L:M_n(\mathbb F)\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb F)$ defined by $L(M)=A^{-1}MA$. Prove that the operator $L$ is diagonalizable and express its eigenvalues and their multiplicities in terms of those of A."

The facts which I know about diagonalizable matrices are:
(1) one can find a basis consisting of its eigenvectors;
(2) its minimal polynomial is in the form of $p(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\cdot\cdot\cdot (x-\lambda_k)$. But I don't know where to start to solve this problem. Hints are preferred.

---

*Thanks for all the help!* I'll try to complete it here:

Let's suppose $L(B)=\lambda B$, this means $\lambda B=A^{-1}BA$, or $\lambda AB=BA$. $A$ is diagonalizable so there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}DP$, where $D$ is diagonal. Then we have,
$$\lambda P^{-1}DPB=BP^{-1}DP \iff \lambda DPBP^{-1}=PBP^{-1}D \iff \lambda DC=CD,$$
where $C=PBP^{-1}$.

Now we aim to understand how $C$ "looks like":
Let $D_{ii}=d_i$ and $D_{ij}=0$. Then we have following,
$$(DC)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n D_{ik}C_{kj} = D_{ii}C_{ij}=d_i C_{ij},$$
$$(CD)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n C_{ik}D_{kj} = C_{ij}D_{jj}=d_j C_{ij}.$$
This implies we have $\lambda d_iC_{ij}= d_jC_{ij}$, or $C_{ij}(\lambda d_i - d_j)=0$.

Comment: Possibly similar questions:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674400/show-that-the-linear-transformation-tv-to-v-defined-by-tb-aba-1-is-dia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $v$ an eigenvector of $A^T$, then $uv^T$ is an eigen"vector" of $L$.

**Alternate Hint:** Consider first the case in which $A$ is diagonal. Then, try to find the new eigenvectors if $A=PDP^{-1}$.

**Alternate Hint:** The matrix of this transformation with respect to the lexicographical basis $\{e_i e_j^T\}$ is $A^{-1}\otimes A$, where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

Comment: Towards your latest edit: it is helpful to rewrite that as
$$
C_{ij} = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad \lambda d_i = d_j
$$
It turns out that there is an "obvious" choice of $n^2$ linearly independent $C$ that will satisfy this condition.

Comment: Hi Omnomnomnom. Thanks for these hints. As for your first hint, I thought about the following: Let $u, v$ be eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^{T}$ respectively, with $Au = \lambda u$ and $A^{T}v=\mu v$. then we have $L(uv^{T})=A^{-1}(uv^{T})A=A^{-1}uv^{T}A=A^{-1}u(A^{T}v)^{T}=\frac{\mu}{\lambda} uv^{T}$. Next we show set {$uv^{T}$} is linear independent and spans the whole $M_n(\mathbb{F})$. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: @mori39 that's right! It's worth noting what that looks like when $A$ is diagonal.