# Left operator on $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ diagnolizable iff A is diagnolizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

**Question**: let $A\in V = M_n(\mathbb{F})$,left translation operator on V is defined as $T:V\rightarrow V,B\rightarrow T(B)=AB$, prove that $T$ is  if and if only A is diagnolizable.

I have found a related problem in this link [prove that operator $L$ on $M_ n (\mathbb{F})$ is diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701052/prove-that-operator-l-on-m-n-mathbb-f-is-diagonalizable).

From this link I get it that if A is diagnolizable under the basis$\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$,then $\{v_iv_j^T\}_{i,j=1,2...,n}$ may be the basis that makes $T$ diagnolizable.

However, I still find it difficult to prove that if  $T$ is diagnolizable, then A is diagnolizable. i.e. when I find a basis which makes $T$ diagnolizable, how can I find the corresponding basis that makes A diagnolizable?

Besides,I find it difficult to 'see' the structure of $T$ if I see $M_n(\mathbb{F})$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. If I see it this way, will it be helpful to solve this problem?

This is the first question that I ever posted here, if there's anything in my question that can be improved,please remind me!!!

Thx!

Comment: Note that $T$ and $A$ have the same minimal polynomial and there is a criterion for diagonalisability in terms of minimal polynomial.

Comment: Could you be more specific about'there is a criterion for diagonalisability in terms of minimal polynomial'?

Comment: The said criterion can be found in practically every introductory linear algebra textbook written for mathematics students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can approach your problem. One direct way is to find the eigenvalues and eigenmatrices of the operator $T$ by solving $T(B)=\lambda B)$, but this may not be the most convenient.

One can use the vectorization operator in order to obtain a matrix representation of the operator $T$. We get that

$$\mathrm{vec}(T(B))=(I_n\otimes A)\mathrm{vec}(B)$$

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product, $\mathrm{vec}$ is the vectorization operator, and the matrix $I\otimes A$ is that representation matrix for the operator $T$. This matrix coincides with a block diagonal matrix with matrices $A$ on the diagonal.

Now, can you show that $M:=I\otimes A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable? From there, can you find the eigenvectors and deduce the eigenmatrices for the operator $T$?

---

Since OP managed to solve the problem, I will complete the solution.

Starting from the definition for $M$ we have that $P$ diagonalizes $A$ if and only if $I\otimes P$ diagonalizes $M$. Now let $P=[v_1,\ldots,v_n]$ and the diagonalizing basis change associated with the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$.

As a result, we have that possible eigenmatrices $B_{ij}$ for $T$ are the matrices corresponding to each column of $I\otimes P$, that is, $B_{ij}=v_ie_j^T$ where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ if the natural basis for $\mathbb{F}^n$. In such a case, we have that $T(B_{ij})=\lambda_i B_{ij}$.

Comment: I find it easy using the  mixed-product property of Kronecker product, since $(P^{-1}\otimes Q^{-1})(I_n\otimes A)(P\otimes Q)=I_n\otimes (Q^{-1}AQ)$,hence the eigenvalues of $T$ are exact those eigenvalues of $A$. Furthermore,the columns of eigenmatrices for the operator $T$ lie in the span of eigenvectors of $A$. Thanks a lot!!!